# PEG-parsing declarations with arbitrary number of qualifiers

Tags: peg

I want to parse for instance:

```
const unsigned int varname;
```

where the number of qualifiers is unknown and the list of qualifier keywords is also unknown (since new ones can be introduced using `using`).

But using the PEG grammar

```
declaration <- qualifier* varname ';'
qualifier <- identifier
varname <- identifier
```

does not work because qualifier* consumes the variable name since it matches. Is there a way to do this or do I have to extract the last identifier manually in the reduction rule?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it.

```
declaration <- qualifier* varname ';'
qualifier <- !varname identifier
varname <- identifier &';'
identifier <- [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ws
ws <- ' '*
```